# Validations selfmade

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-2

So I'm trying to validate some TextFields in javaFX and in my earlier programs this have worked, but I doesn't seem to work now, and I can't figure it out! Several hours have been wasted!

Here is a outcast from my programming
This is ONE class to simplify

```
public class ValidateHelp {

private Text actiontarget = new Text();


public void validateName(TextField firstname, TextField lastname) throws Exception
{
   if(firstname.getText().equals(""))
    {


        if(lastname.getText().equals(""))
            {

            }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    } 
   else
   {
       throw new Exception();
   }
}
```

This is my second class

```
 boolean useTry = true;


    try 
    {
        vh.validateName(firstnameTextField, lastnameTextField);
        firstnameTextField.setText(firstnameTextField.getText());
        lastnameTextField.setText(lastnameTextField.getText());

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        actiontarget.setText("Indtast et fornavn");
        actiontarget.setText("Indtast et efternavn");
        useTry = false;
    }

if(useTry)
        {
             paymentPage();
        }
```

The IF-statement just checks through the validations and when everything is OK it goes to the paymentPage. This is a booking system!

The problem is that it does NOT validate. When I click the "Create member" button I have made it just goes to the payment page, which it shouldn't, because no information have been made in the Firstname and Lastname TextField! 
Hope you can help me !!

Regards
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your if statement is reversed.
Don't want it to throw an exception if either field is empty?

Instead of

```
if(firstname.getText().equals(""))
{


    if(lastname.getText().equals(""))
        {

        }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
} 
else
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

I think you want

```
if(firstname.getText().equals("") || lastname.getText().equals("")){
    throw new Exception();
}
```

That being said, throwing a general exception isn't preferred. At the same time, Exception throwing is somewhat an expensive process execution wise. You could alter your code to just return a boolean of whether it's validated or not & then check that return value instead of throwing and catching exceptions. Just a thought.

Comment: I actually figured it out ! The problem was, that the field HAD to be empty to success. So I made a 

If(firstname.getText().length() > 1)

Comment: In the previous code, you had the requirement that the last name field had to have text in it too. inside your if statement, if(firstname.getText().length() > 1)
I think you want
If(firstname.getText().length() > 1 && lastname.getText().length() > 1)

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to

```
if(methodName.getText().length() > 1)
{

}
```

The problem was that it HAD to be empty to success the validations... so stupid.